# Expression.Call with generic types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, lambda, expression

The class tester is trying to call sum on a generic queryable.  It breaks on the MethodCallExpression.  So I'm not sure if the line below will actually run either.

I've also tried to break out getting the MethodInfo in a separate call but it always returns null.  So I believe finding the "Sum" function with the arguments I have supplied is the trouble.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    class test
    {
        public int sumMe { get; set; }
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void foo()
    {

        var list = new List<test>();
        list.Add(new test() { sumMe = 1 });
        list.Add(new test() { sumMe = 2 });
        list.Add(new test() { sumMe = 3 });

        tester.run(list.AsQueryable(), "sumMe");

    }

    class tester
    {
        public static void run<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, string field)
        {
            ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
            MemberExpression propertyOnInstance = Expression.PropertyOrField(instance, field);

            Type typeOfGenericFunction = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TSource), typeof(int));
            LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeOfGenericFunction, propertyOnInstance, instance);

            MethodCallExpression expr = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Sum", new Type[] { typeof(TSource) }, propertyOnInstance, lambda);
            var hopingThisWorks = source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(expr);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
var sum = new Func<IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, int>>, int>(Queryable.Sum).Method;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That along with a small change,                 `MethodCallExpression expr = Expression.Call(sum, source.Expression, lambdaa);
                object result = Expression.Lambda(expr).Compile().DynamicInvoke();` I was able to make the call.